# Using Regexp for filter on Google Analytics report

Tags: regex, google-analytics

My blog site looks like

```
example.com/us/2012/05/01/blog-post-flowr
example.com/us/2011/05/05/blog-post-trip-to-uganda
example.com/us/2013/11/09/blog-post-thanks.
```

I would like to filter all blog posts for all the years at once. How would I do it using RegExp in Google Analytics?

Will this just do it?

```
(2013)|(2012)|(2011)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If all of your blog posts have a `blog-post-` prefix, just filter for that

If that's not explicit enough, and you want to include the date, you can do `[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/blog-post`

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, the blog-post was for sample. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

You have got the idea, except the parentheses aren't necessary.

Whatever RegExp filters you may want to use, you can test them in the search box:

[image]

Make sure that there are not any monthly or yearly archive pages (e.g. `example.com/us/2013/11/`). To exclude those, you would need

```
2013(......*)|2012(......*)|2011(......*)
```